# Why is my webserver visible on port 80, but not on port 5000 EVEN if explicitly 'sudo ufw allow 5000'?

Tags: ubuntu, python, webserver, python3, port

I have a digital ocean droplet with ubuntu 18.04 and attempting to follow this guide on creating a flask app and hosting with gunicorn + nginx.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

So near the very beginning part of the guide has you create a sample flask app (named myproject.py):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Which you then test exposing to the internet by doing the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
python myproject.py
```

### My Problem:

The app appears to run fine in my terminal but it just fails to load when the browser attempts to visit the url.

Now what's weird for me is if I run those two commands and start the app it produces very normal looking output:

```
(myprojectenv) root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/home/root/myproject# python myproject.py 
 * Serving Flask app "myproject" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I actually go ahead and visit the droplet at the url: http://165.227.205.175:5000 (in google chrome)

I receive the classic "site cannot be reached error":

[image]

Moreover the terminal has received NO NOTIFICATIONS, my flask app is COMPLETELY UNAWARE that someone attempted to visit it.

However, if I change the app instead to:

```
[... flask boilerplate ...]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

And then run:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
python myproject.py
```

I am able to see the site is visible at:  http://165.227.205.175! And moreover the Flask app clearly produces logs (200 request...) Adjusting the code then again slightly (so I am more explicit with my port number) to:

```
[... flask boilerplate ...]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

And again running the commands:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
python myproject.py
```

I now fail to be able to see ANYTHING AGAIN when attempting to load http://165.227.205.175 and once again the flask app seems completely unaware of my browser's attempts to load it.

The output of the "sudo ufw allow 5000" command has consistently been:

```
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

How do I make any kind of progress on this issue?

Comment: does the 5000 port show up in `netstat -ltn | grep -i tcp |grep 5000`?

Comment: so if I run that command in my ssh session nothing comes up at all. it just runs and produces no output. (no errors or other logs produced either)

Comment: that sounds like nothing is listening on port 5000 - I guess the output of `netstat -ltn | grep -i tcp` gives you a list...

Comment: I'm not aware of how Digital Ocean manages the services that people run on them, but is it possible that they have a firewall in front of your "droplet" that blocks port 5000?

Comment: @fcbsd I wasn't sure how to star the server and then run your nestat command (i discovered a utility called "Screen" which lets me have multiple terminals in one ssh session). AFter doing this: the output of the netstat command is ```tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN```

Comment: @Kusalananda is that not what "sudo ufw allow 5000" does? How could i find out if a port is blocked?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas That modifies the firewall on the machine/droplet that you have control over. Between your system and the world, there may be a Digital Ocean-controlled firewall. I somehow doubt that they don't have _any_ intermediate router between your droplet and the world, and that may well filter out certain ports. But, as I said, I have no real insight in what their networking setup looks like.

Comment: Yup, Digital Ocean does have another firewall. It's in the control panel. If it's active, then allow 5000 from there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by destroying my droplet and restarting. I'm not sure what happened to cause it exactly (probably misconfigured firewall) but if you land on this question from the internet i strongly recommend, backup all your code + data and just restarting. It's too easy not to be your first option.